# How to count overlaps and find overlapping partners for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm confused how to most efficiently do this with `pandas`.

I have the following pandas `DataFrame`, which currently contains two columns `starts` and `ends`, representing intervals `[1, 10]`, `[5, 15]`, and `[3, 8]`.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'start': [1, 5, 3], 'end': [10, 15, 8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)
   start  end
0      1   10
1      5   15
2      3    8
```

Beginning at 0, I want to calculate how the intervals overlap. Here is the correct merging structure (without worrying too much about closed/open intervals):

Interval `[0, 1]` has no intervals, `[1,3]` has 1 interval (from `[1, 10]`), `[3, 5]` has two intervals (the pair `[1, 10]` and `[3, 8]`), interval `[5, 8]` has three intervals (`[1, 10], [3, 8], [5,  15]`), `[8, 10]` has two intervals (`[1, 10], [5, 15]`), and etc.

Summarizing the results in table format, the intended result would be:

```
  start  end  total  interval
0      0   1   0     []
1      1   3   1     [[1, 10]] 
2      3   5   2     [[1, 10], [3, 8]]
3      5   8   3     [[1, 10], [3, 8], [5, 15]]
4      8   10  2     [[1, 10], [5, 15]]
5      10  15  1     [[5, 15]]
6      15  75  0     []
```

Whereby the column of `intervals` is currently a list of lists containing each interval list. (I included an integer larger than 15 to make the point that there's nothing there; 75 is arbitrary)

How should I accomplish the above with pandas? The three steps appear to be:

(1) deconstruct the intervals into sections given union of any other intervals

(2) count the overlapping intervals

(3) store the intervals for later retrieval

Is `pandas` even equipped for this operation?

Comment: I don't get the logic for the column `total`

Comment: @U9-Forward I should have named the column better. It means the number of intervals, or the length of the list in column `interval`

Answer (score 3):

From `pandas 0.24.0` one can use `pd.Interval.overlaps`:

```
endpoints = df.stack().sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
intervals = pd.DataFrame({'start':endpoints.shift().fillna(0), 
                          'end':endpoints}).astype(int)
# construct the list of intervals from the endpoints
intervals['intv'] = [pd.Interval(a,b) for a,b in zip(intervals.start, intervals.end)]

# these are the original intervals
orig_invt = pd.arrays.IntervalArray([pd.Interval(a,b) for a,b in zip(df.start, df.end)])

# walk through the intervals and compute the intersections
intervals['total'] = intervals.intv.apply(lambda x: org_intv.overlaps(x).sum())
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+------+-----------+-------+
|    | start  | end  |   intv    | total |
+----+--------+------+-----------+-------+
| 0  |     0  |   1  | (0, 1]    |     0 |
| 1  |     1  |   3  | (1, 3]    |     1 |
| 2  |     3  |   5  | (3, 5]    |     2 |
| 3  |     5  |   8  | (5, 8]    |     3 |
| 4  |     8  |  10  | (8, 10]   |     2 |
| 5  |    10  |  15  | (10, 15]  |     1 |
+----+--------+------+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Using standard for loop approach:

```
bounds = np.unique(df)
if 0 not in bounds: bounds = np.insert(bounds, 0, 0)

end = 75
bounds = np.append(bounds, end)

total = []
interval = []
for i in range(len(bounds)-1):
    # Find which intervals fit
    ix = (df['start'] <= bounds[i]) & (df['end'] >= bounds[i+1])

    total.append(np.sum(ix))
    interval.append(df[ix].values.tolist())

pd.DataFrame({'start': bounds[:-1], 'end': bounds[1:], 'total': total, 'interval': interval})
```

Comment: These approaches are often far more intuitive, though I suppose for loops do take a performance hit. Thanks for this!

Comment: I agree. Readability is worth something. Depending on how computationally heavy your task is, you could easily use this without noticing any difference in computation time. If not, other posts might give you some valuable cut in computation time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `numpy` `boardcast`

```
s1=df1.end.values
s2=df1.start.values
s3=df2.end.values
s4=df2.start.values
f=pd.DataFrame(((s1[:,None]>=s3)&(s2[:,None]<=s4)).T,index=df2.index)
df2['total']=f.sum(1)
df2['interval']=[(df1.values[x]).tolist() for x in f.values]
df2
Out[289]: 
   start  end  total                    interval
0      0    1      0                          []
1      1    3      1                   [[1, 10]]
2      3    5      2           [[1, 10], [3, 8]]
3      5    8      3  [[1, 10], [5, 15], [3, 8]]
4      8   10      2          [[1, 10], [5, 15]]
5     10   15      1                   [[5, 15]]
6     15   75      0                          []
```